# Python Interpolation with Nan values

Tags: python-2.7, interpolation, spline

I'm using an interpolation function on a 2d array. In the array, 3 out of the 4 corners are Nan values -- the interpolation routine works great in this instance. However, when I add NaN in the 4th corner, my return is not the same.

The sample code is as follows:

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

## Create sampling space
x = numpy.linspace(-1,1,11)
y = numpy.linspace(-1,1,11)
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
R = numpy.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

## Create array with NaNs on corners
R[0:2,0:2] = numpy.nan # Works if only this subarray is nan
R[0:2,9:11] = numpy.nan # Works if only this subarray is nan
R[9:11,0:2] = numpy.nan # Works if only this subarray is nan
# R[9:11,9:11] = numpy.nan # Returns nan if only this subarray is nan

## Plot array
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(R)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show();

## Perform interpolation
f = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, R, kx=1, ky=1)
print "f(0.05,0.05) = %.4f" % f(0.05,0.05)
```

Running the above script, my output is: `f(0.05,0.05) = 0.0927`
and my output image shows NaN values in 3 of the 4 corners:[image]

However, when I uncomment the fourth Nan in the array (`R[9:11,9:11] = numpy.nan`), my output becomes: `f(0.05,0.05) = nan`; coincidentally, my plot of the 2d array shows that the fourth corner has NaN values:
[image]

Why is the interpolator value NaN, with this last condition?